# Javascript Promises: Iterate over all object keys arrays and then resolve

Tags: javascript, promise, google-translate

I have this JS object:

```
let setOfWords = {
    "nouns": [
        "work",
        "construction",
        "industry"
    ],
    "verbs": [
        "work"
    ],
}
```

I'm using the google translate API which calls a REST resource, so I need to wait for the response of each translation and then resolve the same object structure but with the translated words.

```
function translateByCategory(){
    let translatedObj = {};
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(category){
            if (translatedObj[category] == undefined) {
                translatedObj[category] = [];
            }
            setOfWords.forEach(function(word){
                google.translate(word, 'es', 'en').then(function(translation){
                    translatedObj[category].push(translation.translatedText);
                });
            });

            // return the translatedObj until all of the categories are translated
            resolve(translatedObj);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Make an array of promises and use `Promise.all` (twice, i.e. for each loop). Don't use `new Promise`.

Comment: @Bergi can you please post a code example? I still can't understand `Promise.all()`

Comment: Btw, are you sure you want to `push` the `word` not the `translation`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all()` to wait for all promise fulfillments (or first rejection):

```
var translateRequests = [];

Object.keys(setOfWords).forEach(function(category){
        setOfWords[category].forEach(function(word){
            translateRequests.push(google.translate(word, 'es', 'en'));
        });
    });
});

Promise.all(translateRequests).then(function(translateResults){
    //do something with all the results
});
```

See the docs: [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Better use `map` instead of `forEach` to construct the array. Though we're gravely missing `concatMap` obviously

Comment: How would you do that cleanly, given that there are nested objects being iterated?

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked with a few modifications but now I understand `Promise.all()`, @Bergi I still returned a Promise but after the children promises where completed.

Answer (score 1):

Individual promises need to be aggregated with `Promise.all()` and fundamentally, that's what's missing.

But you can do better by reducing the number of calls to the Google service.

The Google translate API allows multiple text strings to be translated in one hit by passing an array of words instead of one word per call, giving you a performance advantage though probably not price advantage - google currently charges for its translation service "per character", not "per call".

I can't find any documentation for `google.translate()` but, with a few assumptions, you may be able to write :

```
function translateByCategory(obj, sourceCode, targetCode) {
    let translatedObj = {};
    var promises = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
        return google.translate(obj[key], sourceCode, targetCode).then(function(translations) {
            translatedObj[key] = translations.map(function(t) {
                return t.translatedText || '-';
            });
        }, function(error) {
            translatedObj[key] = [];
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
        return translatedObj;
    });
}
```

If that doesn't work, then [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text) explains how to call google's RESTful translation service directly.

You should be able to write :

```
function translateTexts(baseParams, arrayOfStrings) {
    let queryString = baseParams.concat(arrayOfStrings.map(function(str) {
        return 'q=' + encodeURIComponent(str);
    })).join('&');

    return http.ajax({ // some arbitrary HTTP lib that GETs by default.
        url: 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?' + queryString,
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data.translations.map(function(t) {
            return t.translatedText || '-';
        });
    }, function(error) {
        translatedObj[key] = []; // on error, default to empty array 
    });
}

function translateByCategory(obj, sourceCode, targetCode) {
    let baseParams = [
        'key=' + MY_API_KEY, // from some outer scope
        'source=' + sourceCode, // eg 'en'
        'target=' + targetCode // eg 'es'
    ];
    let translatedObj = {};
    let promises = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
        return translateTexts(baseParams, obj[key]).then(function(translations) {
            translatedObj[key] = translations;
        }, function(error) {
            translatedObj[key] = []; // on error, default to empty array 
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
        return translatedObj;
    });
}
```

In either case, call as follows :

```
let setOfWords = {
    "nouns": [
        "work",
        "construction",
        "industry"
    ],
    "verbs": [
        "work"
    ],
};

translateByCategory(setOfWords, 'en', 'es').then(function(setOfTranslatedWords) {
    console.log(setOfTranslatedWords);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The method suggested by [@hackerrdave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2692595/hackerrdave)  can be modified to make it more compatible with async await feature of JavaScript, do this like the following:

```
function translateByCategory(){

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var translateRequests = [];
        Object.keys(setOfWords).forEach(function(category){
                setOfWords[category].forEach(function(word){
                    translateRequests.push(google.translate(word, 'es', 'en'));
            });
        });
        Promise.all(translateRequests).resolve(resolve(translateRequests));
    });
}
```

So now you can do something like:

```
let translatedObj = await translateByCategory();
```

And you will get what you want in "translatedObj".

Comment: Thanks. I've been reading about `async` and `await`. Isn't it supposed to replace Promises and it works together with `async`? I haven't understand it well though.

Comment: No, `async` and `await` work with Promises, take a look [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/).